# When I change store view that badly affect to front view

Tags: magento2

When I am  changing store view, it affects the whole front end design of my site

How to fix it.

Comment: What problem come or can you also attach screen shot.

Comment: Did you used different language pack for both store views?

Comment: yes, I used different for both.

Comment: you need to apply deploy commands for that..!

Comment: How many language in your website?

Comment: three languages English ,Persian ,Pashto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy for that language pack:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f

Replace **en_US** with your language pack code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this commands:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:clear
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> chmod -R 777 var pub

after that refresh your page.